# What do we 'turn round and say'?

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms

Often you will hear people say something like 'He turned round and called me a liar', or 'what if she turns round and refuses to pay'.

This 'turn round' (I am informed it is much less used in America) is only apposite to certain contexts. And what exactly does it mean?

**Edit after reading some of the responses**

Clearly abruptness and/or suddenness are strongly implied by the expression. But I cannot agree, as some have suggested, that it necessarily involves a reversal of a previous expression. That is not the way it is always used in Britain. For example one colleague to another might say 'If we give Charles added responsibility, he may well turn round and use it as an argument for a pay rise'. That sort of use is quite common.

I think the turning around is not about a reversal of a previous position, but is used to indicate that the remark came suddenly and out of nowhere. In other words the fact of turning around indicates that it is not part of an existing dialogue which had been going on.

Comment: Re: the edit. Why would you think it is anything about abruptness? In the example, it is a change of stance indeed.

Comment: @Kris 'He may well turn round and tell you you are mad.' Where is the reversal in such a remark. Unless 'he' had been in the habit of telling you you were sane, which is unlikely.

Comment: I can't see it as unlikely, rather, it's implied that it is. Anyway, even I am looking for a more authentic explanation of this idiom. Let's see.

Comment: @Kris Well I can assure you people do not use it in the sense of a *volte face*. That is not what it means. It means the 'turner around' did something bold, unusual, or surprising.

Comment: Which is what my comment was about. What makes you think so? Any influencing factors that made you think so? Have you been under some experience(s) that could be the factors?

Comment: @Kris Because the idiom is in everyday use in Britain. And it does not usually mean someone has changed their mind.

Comment: The idiom (as used in the US) refers to a scenario where the person is about to walk away, but they suddenly turn around and get off a "parting shot" before finally leaving (if indeed they do leave).  (And of course the idiom may be used figuratively, where no physical turning or walking is involved.)

Comment: @HotLicks As others have confirmed the expression as used in the UK is not confined to those circumstances. I think user 3847 comes closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an American, I can't say I've heard this very often, either in person or in movies. I think it's more likely used in the UK. But I instantly recognize the meaning. It means to abruptly change tone of speech and/or behavior and confront another person in a critical, hostile or recalcitrant manner. Call it an idiom. In 'what if she turns round and refuses to pay?' she may abruptly change her prior promise to pay and decide to withhold payment. The main idea is the abrupt change of position.

Comment: +1 Yes. I think you are closest so far, especially since you have not referred to any implied reversal of position.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a pleonastic way to express the concept of something that may be said, to give more emphasis to the sentence!

Comment: I think that may be part of the explanation. But see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

*I think the turning around is not about a reversal of a previous position, but is used to indicate that the remark came suddenly and out of nowhere. In other words the fact of turning around indicates that it is not part of an existing dialogue which had been going on.*

Speaking as a Brit, I can confirm your summary to be completely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

No no no.

It comes from The Plague when it was killing so many people that people would speak back to back to avoid catching it. But if you said something particularly controversial or obviously untrue, they may turn round and say it directly to you, risking your death.

Comment: This is in need of some authoritative reference(s).

Comment: This is an interesting answer to a different question. What was asked about was the current meaning and connotation, not the origin of the phrase. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to English David.

Answer (score -1):

***[turn around](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+around)*** and *turn about*

> to reverse direction; to face the opposite direction or turn completely.

Metaphorically, the implication is one of a radical change of one's position/ stand/ opinion on something.

See also, *[turn around](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_around)*

> (transitive, intransitive, reflexive) To change to the opposite direction from a previous position.
>   
> *She **turned** her position **around** and now she is in favor of the merger.*

She must have been against the merger earlier.

Comment: It's really more subtle than that.

Comment: @user2619 Like what? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, Paul Hopper analyzes ‘turn around and’ as an example of hendiadys, a figure of speech used for emphasis.  See this link, beginning on p. 154:  http://books.google.co.th/books?id=l-WbrWslFHQC&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=%22he+turned+round+and%22&source=bl&ots=9do-mAUexF&sig=GLmhyqvafYtu-IuLjuTQ05j-2iU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b2CgU4DPEIqyuAS_9YDgCg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22he%20turned%20round%20and%22&f=false

Comment: Another idea Hopper mentions is that it's an "emergent auxiliary."  In effect, that it is grammaticalizing and losing its literal meaning in the process.

Comment: @user2619 I'm not sure you understand any of these concepts -- not to undermine your efforts though. Neither of those things has anything to do with the question on hand.

Answer (score -1):

In the past to turn around and say was the way to avoid spread of infection and the phrase crept into common speak

Comment: This would be improved with a source reference.